# Will AppStore reject my app if i enable remote notifications in UIBackgroundModes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have an app that uses silent Push notification. To be more precise, My application should update the application badge when a push message is received even if it is running in background. So for that I have enabled Remote notifications under Background Modes and implemented the below method in the code. I want to submit the app to the AppStore. So whether AppStore rejects my app as i enabled the Remote notifications in Background Modes?

---

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Comment: If you app get push message while your app in background mode, the method will not invoked by itselves. It will invoked when user touched the push message banner or popup.

Comment: No it will invoke automatically if it is handled properly in the server. Server side code should include an additional key content-available and the same is to be set to 1. My application is working fine and the above method is getting triggered automatically.. Only doubt is that whether App Store reject my app as i enabled the remote notification .....

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)